# How do I share python variables between scripts?

Tags: python

I want to assign a variable in one file with it's own code. Import it into another one and use the variable.

What i was trying to do was get a username in one script and use it in another.
Here's what I did:

Intro.py

```
def Intro():
    print("Welcome to *game name here*!")
    username = input("What is your username?")
```

Main.py

```
import Intro
Intro.Intro()
print(username)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it that way, because `username` is a local variable inside `Intro` and is not visible anywhere else.

The usual solution to this problem is to *return* the value:

```
def Intro():
    print("Welcome to *game name here*!")
    username = input("What is your username?")
    return username

username = Intro.Intro()
```